# I want to retrive XML node using Jquery or Javascript. Node contains HTML of a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <formnode>
      <form id="somethin" name="something" method="post">
        somefields 
      </form>
     </formnode>`

This is my xml,and I want to render formnode on my `index.php` using Jquery or javascript.
XML is in form of .xml file

Answer (score 0):

first GET your xml file, using ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "yourxml.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            renderXML(xml);
        }
    });
});
```

you can do it like:

```
function renderXML(xmlString) {
    var xml = jQuery(xmlString);
    var form = xml.find("form[name=something]");
    form.remove();
    $("body").append(form);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mehran but I have a xml file not a string and I want to render it from a file

Comment: @user42701: I changed it, take these steps and it should work.

Comment: HTML is not displaying properly as it considers HTML tags as XML tags